# Sampling Variance of OLS Estimators of Regression Coefficients

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am confused about whether the value of the sampling variance of the OLS estimator of a regression coefficient (e.g. slope) differs from sample to sample.

Assume we have the following simple linear regression model:

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

Let $\hat{\beta}_1$ be the OLS estimator of the slope $\beta_1$.

I know that the variance of the sampling distribution of the the OLS estimator $\hat{\beta}_1$ is given by the following:

$Var[\hat{\beta}1]=\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})}$

I am confused because apparently $Var[\hat{\beta}_1]$ is a function of the sample mean $\bar{x}$ which differs from sample to sample, does that mean $Var[\hat{\beta}_1]$ also differs from sample to sample?

In addition, I am wondering how to calculate the sample estimate of $Var[\hat{\beta}_1]$. My understanding is a sample estimate of the true variance of the sampling distribution of $\hat{\beta}_1$ is given by replacing the true error variance $\sigma^2 = Var[\epsilon]$ with the variance of the residual $\hat{\sigma}^2 = Var[\hat{\epsilon}]$ where $\hat{\epsilon} = Y - \hat{Y}$. Is that correct? If so, then the sample estimate of $Var[\hat{\beta}_1]$ is written as:

$\widehat{Var}[\hat{\beta}1] = \frac{\hat{\sigma}^2}{\sum{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - \bar{x})}

But the value of the true sampling variance $Var[\hat{\beta}_1]$ differs from sample to sample, then how can we calculate the bias of the sample estimate $\widehat{Var}[\hat{\beta}_1]$ since the bias would be:

$Bias[\widehat{Var}[\hat{\beta}_1]] = E[\widehat{Var}[\hat{\beta}_1]] - Var[\hat{\beta}_1]$

Comment: Hello and welcome! I suggest https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for your question. The stack posts in that site are also expanding Latex `$ ... $` content to formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will post there!